# Problems sizing PDF pages

Tags: ios, pdf, png

I need to turn pages of PDF documents into separate PNG files, but I'm having problems getting a large enough version of the PDF document into my graphics context. The pages are always around 500 pixels tall, no matter which PDF I try. How can I get larger versions (/higher quality) of each page?

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[_issue objectForKey:@"Issue"] lastPathComponent]];
NSURL *pdfFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfFileUrl);

CGPDFPageRef myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, pageNumber);
CGRect aRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(2008 / (aRect.size.height / aRect.size.width), 2008));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, aRect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 2.0, -1.0);

CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(context, aRect);

CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, pageNumber);
CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFMediaBox, aRect, 0, true);

CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
```

Comment: As far as I can tell here the only way for me to solve this is to scale the PDF page using CGContextScaleCTM(). Anybody that can weigh in on this?

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661479/best-way-to-convert-pdf-to-high-resolution-image-in-cocoa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As iPDFdev answered in the comment, the solution can be found here: [Best way to convert PDF to high-resolution image in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661479/best-way-to-convert-pdf-to-high-resolution-image-in-cocoa)